# Get DEM from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, dem, landsat, google, srtm

How can I get ASTER or SRTM DEM for years like 2016, 2020,... in Google Earth Engine? I can't filter date for SRTM DEM in GEE. It seems that SRTM DEM doesn't have multi-year data, it was captured only in 2000 and available in GEE. So what about ASTER DEM? Can I get it for the year like 2020? How can I filter date for it in GEE? (I can filter ImageCollection like Landsat but for images like DEM I can't filter date.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, ASTER dem is not a temporal dataset, meaning it also has a set temporal resolution. These dems are created using imagery spanning a long time. The latest version of aster dem (ASTGTM) used imagery from March of 2000 to November of 2013 and it combined all the data, meaning that you can't split it by filtering in GEE

Comment: Thank you so much, so how about SRTM???? totally i need dem (ASTER or SRTM) for my field "urban change detection for 20 years" so I downloaded Aster digital elevation model V003 from earthdata.nasa.gov for the years like 2014، 2017، 2020 and I should make mosaic (in arcgis) and merge images but it doesn't merge well(merge with black margin). so i wanted to try it in gee.

Comment: If you are looking at urban change detection I would suggest using optical satellite imagery such as Sentinel-2 or Landsat 8 instead of elevation data. SRTM is also constant in time, so you won't have a lot of temporal data to choose from.